# Do you recommend a textbook on channel estimation of narrowband communications?

Tags: reference-request, channel-estimation

I would like to learn the channel estimation of narrowband communications (i.e., not OFDM).

Do you recommend a textbook (chapter from a textbook) on this subject?

Answer (score 1):

Tse and Visvanath's ["Fundamentals of Wireless Communications"](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Edntse/wireless_book.html) is heavy on the channel and has a good appendix of estimation in additive noise. This might be what you're looking for. Generally, a good book, and free! You'll **really** need to read the first two chapters before delving into the third, I promise.

If you're really more heavily into the estimation theory, Steven M. Kay's "Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing, Volume I: Estimation Theory" is a classic, but I guess pretty much impossible to come by, if your university library doesn't have it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.